# Running a discord.py, pyenv python 3.5.1 script on an apache2 webserver

Tags: python, apache-httpd

I'm running into difficulty getting a python based discord bot to run on my apache2 webserver. I'm using the discord.py api wrapper and I installed python 3.5.1 using pyenv.

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import discord
import asyncio

import requests.packages.urllib3
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!logi'):

        Cmd = message.content.lstrip('!logi ')
        Cmd = Cmd.split()
        From = Cmd[0]
        To = Cmd[2]

        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'starting search for %s to %s' % (From, To))

        To_High=['Hydrogen Fuel','Consumer Technology','Clothing','Domestic Appliances','Animal Meat','Coffee','Fish','Fruit','Grain','Tea','Synthetic Meat','Food Cartridges','Superconductors','Heliostatic Furnaces','Basic Medicines','Paladium','Silver','Gold','Indium','Lithium','Tantalum','Titanium','Uranium','Gallium','Lepidolite','Cobalt','Computer Components','Non-Lethal Weapons']
        From_High=['Pesticides','Agricultural Medicines','Consumer Technology','Synthetic Meat','Progenitor Cells','Advanced Catalysers','Animal Monitors','Awuaponic Systems','Auto Fabricators','Bio Reducing Lichen','H.E. Suits','Resonating Separators','Robotics','Terrain Enrichment Systems','Non-Lethal Weapons','Biowaste','Scrap']

        To_Industrial=['Hydrogen Fuel','Consumer Technology','Clothing','Domestic Appliances','Animal Meat','Coffee','Fish','Fruit','Grain','Tea','Synthetic Meat','Food Cartridges','Algae','Polymers','Semiconductors','Superconductors','Basic Medicines','Progenitor Cells','Gold','Copper','Aluminium','Beryllium','Indium','Lithium','Tantalum','Titanium','Uranium','Gallium','Auto Fabricators','H.E. Suits','Robotics','Leather','Natural Fabrics','Synthetic Fabrics','Non-Lehal Weapons']
        From_Industrial=['Clothing','Domestic Appliances','Food Cartridges','Marine Supplies','Crop Harvesters','Mineral Extractors','Heliostatic Furnaces','Basic Medicines','Computer Components','Biowaste','Scrap']

        To_Agri=['Pesticides','Agricultural Medicines','Hydrogen Fuel','Consumer Technology','Clothing','Domestic Appliances','Animal Meat','Coffee','Fish','Fruit','Grain','Tea','Marine Supplies','Crop Harvesters','Basic Medicines','Progenitor Cells','Animal Monitors','Aquaponic Systems','Terrain Enrichment Systems','Non-Lethal Weapons']
        From_Agri=['Mineral Oil','Animal Meat','Coffee','Fish','Fruit','Grain','Tea','Algae','Leather','Natural Fabrics','Biowaste']

        To_Refinery=['Hydrogen Fuel','Mineral Oil','Consumer Technology','Clothing','Domestic Appliances','Animal Meat','Coffee','Fish','Fruit','Grain','Tea','Synthetic Meat','Food Cartridges','Heliostatic Furnaces','Basic Medicines','Progenitor Cells','Gallite','Indite','Uranimite','Bertrandite','Coltan','Rutile','Advanced Catalysers','Resonating Separators','Non-Lethal Weapons','Scrap']
        From_Refinery=['Hydrogen Fuel','Explosives','Polymers','Semiconductors','Superconductors','Copper','Aluminium','Beryllium','Indium','Lithium','Tantalum','Titanium','Uranium','Gallium','Lepidolite','Cobalt','Synthetic Fabrics','Biowaste']

        To_Extraction=['Hydrogen Fuel','Explosives','Consumer Technology','Clothing','Domestic Appliances','Animal Meat','Coffee','Fish','Fruit','Grain','Tea','Synthetic Meat','Food Cartridges','Mineral Extractors','Basic Medicines','Bio Reducing Lichen','H.E. Suits','Non-Letha; Weapons']
        From_Extraction=['Paladium','Silver','Gold','Gallite','Indite','Uranimite','Bertrandite','Coltan','Rutile','Biowaste']





        if From == 'High-Tech':
            Cmp1 = From_High
        if From == 'Industrial':
            Cmp1 = From_Industrial
        if From == 'Agricultural':
            Cmp1 = From_Agri
        if From == 'Refinery':
            Cmp1 = From_Refinery
        if From == 'Extraction':
            Cmp1 = From_Extraction

        if To == 'High-Tech':
            Cmp2 = To_High
        if To == 'Industrial':
            Cmp2 = To_Industrial
        if To == 'Agricultural':
            Cmp2 = To_Agri
        if To == 'Refinery':
            Cmp2 = To_Refinery
        if To == 'Extraction':
            Cmp2 = To_Extraction


        for x in range(len(Cmp1)):
            for y in range(len(Cmp2)):
                if Cmp1[x] == Cmp2[y]:
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, Cmp1[x])

        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'search finished')


    if message.content.startswith('!fact'):
        print ('received command')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Welcome to Factual-Bot v0.1.0! For all your trading needs!')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Use the !logi command to find profitable trade routes')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'The syntax is !logi [economy1] to [economy2]')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'The following economies are supported')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'High-Tech')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Industrial')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Agricultural')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Refinery')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Extraction')
        print ('transmission sent')


client.run('MTgyODU3ODMyOTM5NTIwMDAz.Ch9bIA.sse2NajDnizDGVxK6BqNIpPg_ng')
```

It runs perfectly fine when I run it with

```
python factual-bot.py
```

but it takes up the shell. I have gotten my webserver to run other python scripts by setting the appropriate "cgi-bin" script extensions and I make all of my scripts 755 in permissions. Nevertheless here is the error apache2 throws up

```
[Fri May 20 00:15:37 2016] [error] [client 192.168.0.4] Premature end of script headers: factual-bot.py
  File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/factual-bot.py", line 12
    async def on_message(message):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Fri May 20 00:15:39 2016] [error] [client 192.168.0.4] Premature end of script headers: factual-bot.py
```

Comment: That error leads me to think that Apache is finding Python 2 instead of 3, since apparently [async was added in 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html?highlight=async#whatsnew-pep-492)

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and it would seem that [screen](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/ssh/using-gnu-screen-to-manage-persistent-terminal-sessions) would be more suitable for my purposes